# Way to always show window tabs in Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

I had this working on an older machine but had to switch computers and lost some preferences along the way. I'm hoping someone here remembers how to do this because I've searched and can't find anything.

Does anyone know the hidden setting for always showing the window tabs even when you only have one document open? I used this a lot to combine disparate open windows and miss it quite a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TextMate’s preferences, select tab “Projects” and check “Document tabs: Show for single document”:

[image: Screenshot]

By the way, to combine (all) disparate open windows into a single one, you might also use the *“Window → Merge All Windows”* command.

Comment: Not sure how I never noticed that checkbox before. I swear I looked there for it. Please accept my belated thanks. :)